# Solr instance for sitecore 7

Tags: solr, sitecore, instance, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

I am trying to implement solr into sitecore but could not find any way for creating a Solr instance for the same. I have few PDFs from SDN I could find any way to create Solr instance in any. Considering that I am new to CMS I hope I could get some help here. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of resources available for setting up Solr, and integrating Sitecore.

Essentially Sitecore is ignorant with respects to how you setup Solr (barring a few exceptions), so you need to follow standard methods to set Solr up. If you are doing this on your local machine, then I recommend you simply download Solr and get it running through the provided Jetty App Server.

Once Solr is running, download the Solr Extensions from SDN, then follow the search scaling guide to integrate Solr. This really only boils down to the following;

- Remove Lucene config files
- Add Solr config files and binaries
- Add Solr endpoint into relevant config
- Generate Solr Schema via Sitecore -> Control Panel -> Search (within Sitecore)
- Add Schema file to Solr Core configuration
- et voila

There is a great guide here: http://www.dansolovay.com/2013/05/setting-up-solr-with-sitecore-7.html

Comment: Isn't lucene required when using Solr?

Comment: No, Solr is actually built on top of Lucene, but that all comes packaged with Solr itself. Therefore on Sitecore's side, Lucene would not be required.

Comment: Hi @PizzaTheHut! I am installing SOLR as per the link that you have provided but I am stuck at a point where it asks to merge the xml files! **It says this 'If you have any other field definitions, copy fields or dynamics fields configured in your schema they are overwritten by the schema generator. To preserve these fields, copy your original schema and merge it with the newly generated schema afterwards**

Comment: Make sure you are using a Solr version less than 4.8, or that you are applying the schema fixes for later versions as described in the document. You might need to open a different question to provide more context and information for a good answer.